# Inerting Matrikon OPC DA data into postgreSQL with Matrikon ODBC Client

Tags: opc

I have Matrikon OPC Simulation server and Matrikon ODBC Client
I have connected matrikon ODBC client to MySQl database..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrEtY.png)
As I have configured ODBC client shown in image. The issue I am facing is it is not inserting/updating data into mysql database. Not getting connection hasbeen established but data is not getting inserted into table.

I have tried changing couple of settings in ODBC client that diddn't help.